# How to limit knp_paginator from extending?

Tags: symfony, knppaginator

I want to limit the pagination boxes going for ever. Say there is 100 events loaded -> 3 events are displayed/page; and such that the pagination boxes `[1][2][3][4]....[40]` doesn't go on...

[image: FYI: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

In `config.yml` add this:

```
knp_paginator:
   page_range: 5 # number of links showed in the pagination menu (e.g: you have 10 pages, a page_range of 3, on the 5th page you'll see links to page 4, 5, 6)
```

If you need change the sliding use any of these:

```
template:                                        
    pagination: '@KnpPaginator/Pagination/sliding.html.twig'

@KnpPaginator/Pagination/sliding.html.twig (by default)
@KnpPaginator/Pagination/twitter_bootstrap_v3_pagination.html.twig
@KnpPaginator/Pagination/twitter_bootstrap_pagination.html.twig
@KnpPaginator/Pagination/foundation_v5_pagination.html.twig
```

Answer (score 0):

***I guess that knp paginator does that for you*** but in case it does not You could try to modify any of the templates above to do something like this:

> set a control variable

```
{% if pageCount > maxNumberOfBoxes %}
        {% set breakpointAdded=true %}
{% endif %}
```

then find the loop which look like this

```
{% for page in pagesInRange %}
            {% if page != current %}
                <span class="page">
                <a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({(pageParameterName): page})) }}">{{ page }}</a>
            </span>
            {% else %}
                <span class="current">{{ page }}</span>
            {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
```

and replace it for something like this(with your own logic of course)

```
{% for i in range(0,pageCount) %}
                {% if i > xBreakpoint and i < yBreakpoint and breakpointAdded == false %}
                    <span class="dots">...</span>
                    {% set breakpointAdded = true %}
                {% else %}
                    {% if page != current %}
                        <span class="page">
                            <a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({(pageParameterName): page})) }}">{{ page }}</a>
                       </span>
                    {% else %}
                        <span class="current">{{ page }}</span>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
```

if anything of this works you could try to modify the getPaginationData function from SlidingPagination class.

what ever works for you.

Comment: Please if one of the answers worked for you follow this [doc](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) in order to end this topic.